# calling function with ajax, part working but part not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Sorry if the title isn't very clear. I have search engine that works with ajax function. Right now if I type t in a search box, the tags that contain the word t shows up(ex if I type t, then test shows up) but thing is after I delete the word t all the tags show up in the result part. Does this make sense? if I'm not clear I'll post the picture. I'm not sure why or how to fix this. 
Here;s my code.

```
<h3>Search</h3>
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" onkeyup="handle_keyup()"/>

<ul id="search-results">

</ul>
```

Here I can't delete search-results as this will show the search results but on this section when nothing is typed still all the tags show up. (it only shows all when I finish using search bar)

my ajax

```
function handle_keyup() {

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/search/",
           data: { 
               'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
           },
           success: searchSuccess,
           dataType: 'html'
       });

   };


function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
   $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

problem is probably occurring from up there, but I'll post the back end as well. This is python django framework.

```
def search_titles(request):
# categories = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.POST.get('search_text', ''))
    categories = Category.objects.filter(name__icontains=request.POST.get('search_text', ''))
    return render_to_response('main/ajax_search.html', {'categories' : categories})
```

ajax_Search.html

```
{% if categories.count > 0 %}

{% for category in categories %}
   <li><a href="/category/{{category.name}}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}

<li>None to show!</li>


{% endif %}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when the user "deletes" the word, your `handle_keyup` function is fired, sending a search request of `''` to the server.

The server then looks for the empty string `''` in the category names and finds it in all of them.

One approach is for the server to check if the search text is empty, and if it is, return nothing.  Something like:

```
def search_titles(request):
    txt = request.POST.get('search_text', '') 
    if txt:
        categories = Category.objects.filter(name__icontains=txt)
    else:
        categories = []

    return render_to_response('main/ajax_search.html', {'categories' : categories})
```

Comment: thank you this seems valid but when I tried it, it gave me a syntax error in          categories = Category.objects.filter(name__icontains=txt))
not sure why because it seems valid, I did tabbed in the right places. Is there a way to fix this problem other way?

Comment: hmm this really seems like no error simple code, but why getting syntax error?

Comment: you put two )) there, after fixing that search functionality doesn't work

Comment: I would check `txt` against empty string in your if. Like this: `if txt != '':`